# Delphi THMTLFrameBrowser font increase

Tags: delphi

I'm working in Delphi with the `THTMLViewer` and `THTMLFrameBrowser` components. Does any one know how to dynamically increase all of the font sizes in the currently loaded HTML page when using PBear's component?  Changing the `DefFontSize` will only have an effect if the current page is reloaded.  The same question applies to the `MarginWidth` and `MarginHeight` properties.  Reloading the page will work, but it seems like overkill.

Isn't there a way to redraw the HTML without reloading the currently loaded HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem, and I came to the conclusion that the page must be reloaded, there is no other way.